# Custom Alert Dialog gives a lot of Resouce Compat error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am just creating simple custom alert dialog. But it gives me a lot of error related to Resouce Compat:

**Creation of alert dialog:**

```
class CustomLoadingDialog(
    activity: Activity
) {

    private val dialog: Dialog
    private val view: View
    private val textViewDialogMessage: TextView

    init {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_loading_dialog,null)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setCancelable(true)
        dialog = builder.create()
        textViewDialogMessage= view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDialogMessage)
    }

    fun showDialog() {
        dialog.show()
    }

    fun updateText(text: String) {
        textViewDialogMessage.text = text
    }

    fun dismissDialog() {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

**Using in fragment:**

```
private val customLoadingDialog by lazy {
    CustomLoadingDialog(requireActivity())
}

private lateinit var show: Button


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    show = view.findViewById(R.id.show)

    show.setOnClickListener {
        customLoadingDialog.showDialog()
        customLoadingDialog.updateText("hello")
    }

}
```

**Errors:**

```
W/ResourcesCompat: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f03010b a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:179)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:66)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:86)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:226)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createButton(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:43)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:156)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.CustomLoadingDialog.<init>(CustomLoadingDialog.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:23)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.getCustomLoadingDialog(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.onViewCreated$lambda$0(BleDeviceFragment.kt:41)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.$r8$lambda$NHQbEvPTnAuFUS-VgtasillTOTk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27654)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
W/ResourcesCompat: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300fc a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:65)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:240)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createButton(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:43)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:156)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.CustomLoadingDialog.<init>(CustomLoadingDialog.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:23)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.getCustomLoadingDialog(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.onViewCreated$lambda$0(BleDeviceFragment.kt:41)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.$r8$lambda$NHQbEvPTnAuFUS-VgtasillTOTk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27654)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
W/ResourcesCompat: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f03010b a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:65)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.loadFromAttributes(MaterialButtonHelper.java:109)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:251)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createButton(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:43)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:156)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.CustomLoadingDialog.<init>(CustomLoadingDialog.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:23)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.getCustomLoadingDialog(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.onViewCreated$lambda$0(BleDeviceFragment.kt:41)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.$r8$lambda$NHQbEvPTnAuFUS-VgtasillTOTk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27654)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
W/ResourcesCompat: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300fc a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:529)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:160)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:125)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:104)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.inflateColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:262)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getColorStateList(ResourcesCompat.java:236)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList(ContextCompat.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:48)
        at com.google.android.material.resources.MaterialResources.getColorStateList(MaterialResources.java:65)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonHelper.loadFromAttributes(MaterialButtonHelper.java:115)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:251)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.<init>(MaterialButton.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createButton(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:43)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:156)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1144)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1105)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.CustomLoadingDialog.<init>(CustomLoadingDialog.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:23)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$customLoadingDialog$2.invoke(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.getCustomLoadingDialog(BleDeviceFragment.kt:22)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.onViewCreated$lambda$0(BleDeviceFragment.kt:41)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment.$r8$lambda$NHQbEvPTnAuFUS-VgtasillTOTk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.testm.testuygulama.ui.BleDeviceFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7184)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1202)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7157)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:821)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27654)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Probably you will get some kind of error when using simple custom alert dialog like above. Because the project is really simple. How can i get rid of these errors?

**custom_loading_dialog:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDialogMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDialogDismiss"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textViewDialogMessage" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share with us the `custom_loading_dialog` XML

Comment: Try to remove `style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.TextButton"` and check if you will get the same issue